# Change FlexLM license from floating to node-locked

Tags: flexlm

My development environment previously used a FlexLM floating license on a Windows XP machine. Now I want to change the license to a node-locked license. Therefor I defined environment variable LM_LICENSE_FILE. But when I use the development environment I get the error that the license server is down or not responding. As license files it mentions the license server and the new license file. So, the new license file is added but still the connection to the server is used as first and only option. How can I tell the development environment that the license server is obsolete and should not be used anymore?

Answer (score 1):

Each editor define if you could alone change the model license : floating to node locked. Some editors must send you a new licenses file to authorize this usage.

If you could alone change the model license, you must modify your option file associated with the license file.

The variable 'LM_LICENSE_FILE' give only the reference of the license server to use. There is no notion of model license.